# TinyMCE onPaste function, text position

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I need custom onPaste() TinyMCE (version 4) function.

With mouse right click and paste button - works fine, but with CTR + V always text jump to content bottom.

Why CTRL + V ignore cursor position?

```js
function pasteText(editor) {
  editor.onPaste.add(function(editor, e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var content = 'My content: ' + ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('text/plain');

    editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content);
  });
};
```